# receiving all data from having access to an id from firebase Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I have a collection in firebase that is filled with a number of different id's from other collections. I have access to one of these ids and from this I am trying to access that id in the other collection and get that information.

I have my id here:

```
export class PvPropertyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() viewing: TenantViewingModel;
  private property;
  private propertyId;
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.propertyId = this.viewing.property_id;
    console.log(this.propertyId)
  }


}
```

which logs:

```
Q1sHTyPDSnxCQOpZ14jU (which is the id)
```

I am getting this id from my 'viewings' collection, but not want to use this id to access its content within the 'properties' collection on firebase. Anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: Do you want to access the data inside that object?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yes i do